# Bloodbonding an Assamite?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-20th-anniversary

Assamites of the order have a terrible curse: They take an automatic, unsoakable point of lethal or even aggravated damage if they so much as ingest any Vitae that is not their own.<sup>1</sup>

Now, blood bonding requires to give someone to ingest at least one blood point at multiple occasions.<sup>2</sup>

Because the Assamite takes damage, it can be presumed, that they notice *at once* that they were fed Vitae, and there is no way to sneak it by them. With the First drink effects the Assamite would also quite assuredly know who was the culprit - and might as well use the first drink's effect to find them for a little... hit on their own, or just pay another member of the Web of Knives to get rid of them...

But does the taking damage actually have any other effect on the formation of the blood bond, or does it make resisting a formed blood bond easier, as taking that aggravated damage is highly unpleasant?

---

1 - V20, p.49
2 - V20, p.286

Comment: It's worth noting that according to the metaplot in *Becket's Jyhad Diary,* the rise of Ur-Shulgi brought forth an end to that curse.

Comment: Afterwards, trying it is is even **worse** - they'll go frenzy and suck you dry.

Answer (score 6):

### It has no predefined impact.

The formation of the bond is not influenced by the pain or damage inflicted in the drinking. Modifications of the difficulty to resist commands by the domitor is at the discretion of the Storyteller (V20, p.288), but there's no prescribed effect.